# Creating SuperUser on a custom database (not default)

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a multi-tenant django application. Since the requirement of multi-tenancy, for starters, I have created a second database. However, I am unable to create a SuperUser in the newly created database.

I did try the answer listed [Django fails to create superuser in other db than 'default'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453810/django-fails-to-create-superuser-in-other-db-than-default)
However, no luck. 
Getting the following output on compile:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly co
nfigured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more
details.

Settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'Alora': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'Alora',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'somepassword',
    }
}
```

Python Version

```
C:\Users\User>python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

Django Version

```
C:\Users\User>django-admin --version
2.2
```

Tried python manage.py createsuperuser --database=Alora.
Received the error stated above.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `default` database configuration is empty, it is trying to connect to that one, your error message: `Please supply the ENGINE value` is about the default database

Comment: @Seraf, thanks for the reply!However, I am trying to create the superuser on 'Alora' database.

Comment: You must supply 'default' database even for running something on secondary database. Otherwise django will complain.

Comment: Thank you! that solved the issue.